# Ruby On Rails, week number is not the correct one (-1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, week-number

I need the current week number, if I'm not totally mistaken it's week 51 right now? However when testing it in the console I get this.

```
Time.now
=> 2013-12-19 11:08:25 +0100
Time.now.strftime('%U')
=> "50"

Date.today
=> Thu, 19 Dec 2013
Date.today.strftime("%U").to_i
=> 50
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Time.now.strftime('%V')` will give you the week number according to ISO 8601.

Answer (score 8):

```
why is that?
```

according to **%U** or **%W**, The days in the year before the first week are in week 0 (00..53).

with **%V** (as @Graeme McLean wrote), The days in the year before the first week are in the last week of
the previous year (01..53).

From [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime).

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, I'm unsure as to why it is that way, but to get the correct one using Ruby, I use this:

```
require 'Date'

week_number = Date.today.cweek #=> 51
```

Comment: In case anyone lands here looking for what I was looking for (even/odd weeks in Ruby on Rails), the above answer is helpful. You can then do `week_number.even?` or `week_number.odd?`.